# In react, reset password with email functionality

Tags: reactjs

I used the react app and however I did not realize until recently that, I also need a reset-password email functionality.

So I am stuck in react forget password page.

Here is my code:
Index.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import Layout from "../MyLayout";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import CheckButton from "react-validation/build/button";
import Input from "react-validation/build/input";
import Form from "react-validation/build/form";
import AuthService from "../../services/auth.service";
import {isEmail} from "validator";

const required = (value) => {
    if (!value) {
        return (
            <span style={{display: 'block'}} className="form-inlineMessage error">
                This field is required!
            </span>
        );
    }
};

function ForgotPassword(props) {
    const form = useRef();
    const checkBtn = useRef();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
        const email = e.target.value;
        setEmail(email);
    };
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setMessage("");
        setLoading(true);
        form.current.validateAll();
        if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
            AuthService.forgotPassword(email).then((response) => {
                    setMessage(response.message);
                    setLoading(false);
                    // props.history.push("/login");
                },
                (error) => {
                    const resMessage =
                        (error.response &&
                            error.response.data &&
                            error.response.data.message) ||
                        error.message ||
                        error.toString();
                    setLoading(false);
                    setMessage(resMessage);
                }
            );
        } else {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };
    return (
        <Layout>
            <section className="breadcrumbs">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="breadcrumb">
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                            <li>Reset Password</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section className="forget_page_Mn">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="page_heading text-center">
                        <h1>Reset your password</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-content_text text-center">
                        <p>We will send you an email to reset your password.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="forget_page_wrapper">
                        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={form}>
                            <div className="forget_form form_Mn">
                                <div className="form-field">
                                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor="reset_email">Email Address<span className="required">*</span></label>
                                    <Input
                                        type="text"
                                        className="form-input"
                                        name="email"
                                        value={email}
                                        onChange={onChangeUsername}
                                        validations={[required]}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-actions text-center">
                                    <button className="button btn-secondry" name="button" disabled={loading}>
                                        {loading && (
                                            <i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"/>
                                        )}
                                        <span>Submit</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                {message && (
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <span style={{display: 'block'}} className="form-inlineMessage error text-center">
                                            {message}
                                         </span>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                                <CheckButton style={{display: "none"}} ref={checkBtn}/>
                                <div className="form-actions-alredy-customer text-center">
                                    <p className="alredy-customer-link">Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Log In</Link></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </Layout>
    )
}
export default ForgotPassword;
```

AuthController.js

```
exports.forgotPassword = function (req, res) { 
  
    var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)); 
     
    var error_msg = '';
    if(!input.email){
        error_msg = 'Please provide valid E-mail Address.';
    }   
    if(error_msg != ''){ 
        return res.send(JSON.stringify({
            "status": failStatus,
            "message": error_msg,  
        })); 
    }else{

        var userData = { 
            email    : input.email
        };

        var responseArr = {};  
        Users.checkEmailExist(result){  
            if(result[0].count && result[0].count > 0){ 
                updateData = {
                    reset_password_code : randomstring.generate(10), 
                    email : input.email
                } 
                Users.updateData(updateData,function(updateResult){  
                    if(updateResult){      
                        Users.getUserByEmail(input.email,function(userDetail){
                            // Send mail to user 
                            var mailData = { 
                                'receiver_id' :  userDetail[0].id,  
                                'template_slug' : 'forgot-password' 
                            }  
                            Mails.SendMail(mailData);  
                            responseArr.user_id = userDetail.id;  
                            // Save Business profile 
                            return res.send(JSON.stringify({  
                                "status": successStatus,
                                "message": 'Reset password link is sent to your email. Please check.', 
                                "data": responseArr,         
                            }));  
                        }); 

                    }else{ 
                        return res.send(JSON.stringify({ 
                            "status": failStatus,  
                            "message": 'Data could  not updated. Please try again.',
                            "data": '{}'  
                        })); 
                    }   
                }); 
            }else{
                return res.send(JSON.stringify({ 
                    "status": SessionExpireStatus,  
                    "message": 'Email is not registered.',
                    "data": responseArr  
                })); 
            }
        });   
           
    }
    return false;  
};
```

MailController.js

```
exports.SendMail = function (mail_data){     

    console.log(mail_data);   
    connectPool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        connection.release(); 
        console.log(' Error getting mysql_pool connection: ' + err);
        throw err;
    } 
    connection.query('SELECT * from users where id = ? ',[mail_data.receiver_id], function(error, result){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);   
        }else{
  
            var userDetail = result;   
            //console.log(userDetail); //return true; 
            connection.query('SELECT subject,description from email_templates where slug = ? ',[mail_data.template_slug],function(err,emailTempalate) {   
                if(userDetail[0].first_name){
                    connection.release();     
                       
                    var body_message = emailTempalate[0].description;  
                    body_message =  body_message.replace('[[NAME]]',userDetail[0].first_name);  
                     
                    // Reset password link
                    var resetPasswordLink = WebsiteURL+"resetPassword/"+userDetail[0].reset_password_code; 
                    body_message =  body_message.replace('[[PASSWORD_RESET_URL]]',resetPasswordLink);
                    body_message =  body_message.replace('[[PASSWORD_RESET_URL]]',resetPasswordLink);
                    body_message =  body_message.replace('[[PASSWORD_RESET_URL]]',resetPasswordLink);
   
                    var subject =  emailTempalate[0].subject; 
                    var mail = {
                        from    :   'google.com <google@gmail.com>',
                        to      :   [String(userDetail[0].email)],   
                        subject :   subject,   
                        html    :   body_message   
                    }   
                    smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
                        if(error){  
                            console.log(error); 
                            smtpTransport.close(); 
                            return res.send(JSON.stringify({
                                "status": 201,
                                "message": 'Error in sending mail.',
                                "data": error, 
                             })); 

                        }else{   
                            console.log('mail sent'); 
                            smtpTransport.close();
                            return res.send(JSON.stringify({
                                "status": 201,
                                "message": 'Password reset successful.
                                "data": data,   
                            }));  
                        }     
                    }); 


                }else{
                    console.log(userDetail+mail_data);   
                }
                 
                 
            }); 
        }
     });   
    }); 
}
```

If anybody has any suggestions as to how I can go about this? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what is working and what is not working? It also helps to try and reduce the code in your question down to just the bare minimum.

Comment: Yes, forgot password page is ready but I entered email to reset password but it is not going.

Comment: well fist of all you have a typo I think in `"message": 'Password reset successful.` you are missing a closing quote and a `,` at th end. now if that is the case, edit it and try again. if in your code is correct, then you should provide us with somekind of an error message or from which point after exactly the whole thing stops working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked this and there are some changes in the code which have been done.

Index.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import Layout from "../MyLayout";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import CheckButton from "react-validation/build/button";
import Input from "react-validation/build/input";
import Form from "react-validation/build/form";
import AuthService from "../../services/auth.service";
import {isEmail} from "validator";

const required = (value) => {
    if (!value) {
        return (
            <span style={{display: 'block'}} className="form-inlineMessage error">
                This field is required!
            </span>
        );
    }
};
const vemail = value => {
    if (!isEmail(value)) {
        return (
            <span style={{display: 'block'}} className="form-inlineMessage error">Please use a valid email address, such as user@example.com.</span>
        );
    }
};
function ForgotPassword(props) {
    const form = useRef();
    const checkBtn = useRef();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
        const email = e.target.value;
        setEmail(email);
    };
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setMessage("");
        setLoading(true);
        form.current.validateAll();
        if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {
            AuthService.forgotPassword(email).then((response) => {
                    setMessage(response.message);
                    setLoading(false);
                    // props.history.push("/login");
                },
                (error) => {
                    const resMessage =
                        (error.response &&
                            error.response.data &&
                            error.response.data.message) ||
                        error.message ||
                        error.toString();
                    setLoading(false);
                    setMessage(resMessage);
                }
            );
        } else {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };
    return (
        <Layout>
            <section className="breadcrumbs">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="breadcrumb">
                        <ul>
                            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                            <li>Reset Password</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section className="forget_page_Mn">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="page_heading text-center">
                        <h1>Reset your password</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-content_text text-center">
                        <p>We will send you an email to reset your password.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="forget_page_wrapper">
                        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={form}>
                            <div className="forget_form form_Mn">
                                <div className="form-field">
                                    <label className="form-label" htmlFor="reset_email">Email Address<span className="required">*</span></label>
                                    <Input
                                        type="text"
                                        className="form-input"
                                        name="email"
                                        value={email}
                                        onChange={onChangeUsername}
                                        validations={[required, vemail]}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-actions text-center">
                                    <button className="button btn-secondry" name="button" disabled={loading}>
                                        {loading && (
                                            <i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"/>
                                        )}
                                        <span>Submit</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                {message && (
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <span style={{display: 'block'}} className="form-inlineMessage error text-center">
                                            {message}
                                         </span>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                                <CheckButton style={{display: "none"}} ref={checkBtn}/>
                                <div className="form-actions-alredy-customer text-center">
                                    <p className="alredy-customer-link">Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Log In</Link></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </Layout>
    )
}
export default ForgotPassword;
```

AuthController.js

```
exports.forgotPassword = function (req, res) { 
  
    var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)); 
     
    var error_msg = '';
    if(!input.email || input.email == null){
        error_msg = 'Please provide valid E-mail Address.';
    }   
    if(error_msg != ''){ 
        return res.send(JSON.stringify({
            "status": failStatus,
            "message": error_msg,  
        })); 
    }else{

        var userData = { 
            email    : input.email
        };

        var responseArr = {};  
        Users.checkEmailExist(userData,function(result){  
            if(result[0].count && result[0].count > 0){ 
                updateData = {
                    reset_password_code : randomstring.generate(10), 
                    email : input.email
                } 
                Users.updateData(updateData,function(updateResult){  
                    if(updateResult){      
                        Users.getUserByEmail(input.email,function(userDetail){
                            // Send mail to user 
                            var mailData = { 
                                'receiver_id' :  userDetail[0].id,  
                                'template_slug' : 'forgot-password' 
                            }  
                            Mails.SendMail(mailData);  
                            responseArr.user_id = userDetail.id;  
                            // Save Business profile 
                            return res.send(JSON.stringify({  
                                "status": successStatus,
                                "message": 'Reset password link is sent to your email. Please check.', 
                                "data": responseArr,         
                            }));  
                        }); 

                    }else{ 
                        return res.send(JSON.stringify({ 
                            "status": failStatus,  
                            "message": 'Data could  not updated. Please try again.',
                            "data": '{}'  
                        })); 
                    }   
                }); 
            }else{
                return res.send(JSON.stringify({ 
                    "status": SessionExpireStatus,  
                    "message": 'Email is not registered.',
                    "data": responseArr  
                })); 
            }
        });   
           
    }
    return false;  
};
```

[image]
Note: MailController.js code is correct, it does not have any changes.

I hope it works for you. Best of luck!